# How to remove the image attributes of a rendered image field

Tags: field

I'm rendering the image like :

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field(Model.ImageId, Model.InnerItem)
```

which is rendering the image like this:

```
<img src="/-/media/finance.png?h=400&amp;iar=0&amp;w=592&amp;hash=3A3B586AFFE041EA4614989C119A8387" alt="finance" width="592" height="400">
```

I would like to remove all the query string params and also the width, height attributes.

The following approach has no effect. The else condtion does gets hit though.

```
public class RemoveImageHeightWidthAttributes
    {
        public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            if (args.FieldTypeKey != "image")
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string imageTag = args.Result.FirstPart;
                imageTag = Regex.Replace(imageTag, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+height\s*=\s*\S+", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                imageTag = Regex.Replace(imageTag, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+h\s*=\s*\S+", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                imageTag = Regex.Replace(imageTag, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+width\s*=\s*\S+", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                imageTag = Regex.Replace(imageTag, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+w\s*=\s*\S+", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                imageTag = Regex.Replace(imageTag, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+iar\s*=\s*\S+", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                imageTag = Regex.Replace(imageTag, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+hash\s*=\s*\S+", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);                    
                args.Result.FirstPart = imageTag;
            }
        }
    }
```

using Sitecore 10.1

Comment: Would seem like removing the height and width would go against best practices. Those would allow the browser to maintain the proper dimensions before the image downloads.

Comment: I don't think you can/should remove the hash -- it's there for security reasons. Can you share why you want to remove all the query strings? Perhaps there is a better solution.

Comment: @SashaKachanov Ok then can keep the hash. The image doesn't look good with the params & the attributes. If I replace it with the url of image in server, it looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems with the RegEx. Here is the complete solution that worked for me.

**1. Create a patch config**

[image]

**2. And the class:**

```
    namespace MyProject.Foundation.Common.Pipelines
    {
    using HtmlAgilityPack;
    using Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField;
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class RemoveImageAttributes
    {
        public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (args.FieldTypeKey != "image")
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    string imageTag = args.Result.FirstPart;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageTag) && (imageTag.ToLower().Contains("width=") || imageTag.ToLower().Contains("height=")))
                    {
                        /// Approach 1:
                        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
                        document.LoadHtml(imageTag);
                        HtmlNode image = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")[0];

                        if (image != null)
                        {
                            if (image.Attributes["width"] != null)
                            {
                                image.Attributes["width"].Remove();
                            }
                            if (image.Attributes["height"] != null)
                            {
                                image.Attributes["height"].Remove();
                            }

                            args.Result.FirstPart = image.OuterHtml;
                        }
                        
                        /// Approach 2: to remove attributes using Regex
                        //imageTag = Regex.Replace(imageTag, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+width\s*=\s*\S+", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        //imageTag = Regex.Replace(imageTag, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+height\s*=\s*\S+", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        //args.Result.FirstPart = imageTag;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log error
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your query string by these ways

-The hash in the query string comes from Sitecore and can be triggered with the setting "Media.RequestProtection.Enabled"  (originally set in Sitecore.Media.RequestProtection.config),it isn't recommended to remove the hash

-The width and height in the query string can also be modified in the same config file if you have custom image scaling.

-If you don't have the custom scaling and you want to remove it then you can done it with some properties [here](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/media-options-and-query-string-parameters-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms), or by adding patch config files [refer [here]](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/build-item-and-media-urls.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@{

string imgURL = "";
string altText = "";
Item item = Model.InnerItem;

if (item != null)
{
    ImageField imgField = ((ImageField)item.Fields["ImageFieldName"]); //Add your image field name here.

    if (imgField != null && imgField.MediaItem != null)
    {
        imgURL = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem);

        altText = imgField.Alt;
    }
}}
```